Access denied while loading svg in vscode extension and icons showing alt values
I'm currently working on building a vscode/azure data studio extension relying on a webview in Vue / Quasar.
At first, I had material icons used as default icons, so a workaround was to install the font locally on the machine. But not scalable at all.
So I thought that maybe using the default vue icons would work.
After fidgeting with the CSP's i managed to remove errors about loading js/css and now i'm stuck at loading the svg icons embeded in Quasar's components.
This is what I have :
https://i.sstatic.net/B770b.png
CPS's:
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self';
          script-src vscode-resource: vscode-webview: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https:;
          style-src vscode-resource: vscode-webview: 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
          img-src vscode-resource: vscode-webview: 'self' "/>

EDIT:
The icons.svg file trying to be loaded is my custom icons.
So I have two problems now. The default quasar icons are showing their literal name like this :
https://i.sstatic.net/xR3po.png
